# Undefined variables passed to data

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

In this block of code undefined variables passed to data

```
 var data, expContainerSettings;
 $( this ).hide();
 $( '<span class="placeholder" style="display: none;"></span>' ).insertAfter( this );
 $( this ).detach().prependTo( target ).data( 'collapsibleTabsSettings', data );
 $( this ).attr( 'style', 'display: list-item;' );
 data = $.collapsibleTabs.getSettings( $( ele ) );
 if ( data )
 {
   expContainerSettings = $.collapsibleTabs.getSettings( $( data.expandedContainer ) );
   if ( expContainerSettings )
   {
       expContainerSettings.shifting = false;
       $.collapsibleTabs.handleResize();
   }
 }
```

It looks like the mistake here

```
$( this ).detach().prependTo( target ).data( 'collapsibleTabsSettings', data );
```

how i can fix this?

Comment: `data` ***is*** undefined in that code ?

Comment: `var data, expContainerSettings;`  <-- Setting to undefined!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value you want on the `data` variable before you pass it to the `data` method. As it stands, you are passing `undefined`, because you simply declare the variable:

```
var data, expContainerSettings; // <-- Both of these are undefined.
```

In JavaScript, you don't have access to change the value of a variable after you pass it to a function.

As long as no asynchronous operations are happening, the solution might be as simple as executing this line:

```
data = $.collapsibleTabs.getSettings( $( ele ) );
```

Before executing this line:

```
$( this ).detach().prependTo( target ).data( 'collapsibleTabsSettings', data );
```

Comment: What's changed? I see there were some revisions, but it looks like you deleted them all.